# Mask Password Input in a Console App

Tags: delphi, console, console-application

I am writing a console application using BDE 2006 and I want it to be able to prompt for a password string and mask it with "*" as the user is typing. I have looked around but I could not find examples of how to do this. Everything I saw was how to do this in TEdit. Any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,

Nic

Comment: if you aren't going to use a TEdit, what control do you want to use for the user to type in the username and password?

Comment: In a console window. He mentions it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

function GetPassword(const InputMask: Char = '*'): string;
var
  OldMode: Cardinal;
  c: char;
begin
  GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), OldMode);
  SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), OldMode and not (ENABLE_LINE_INPUT or ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT));
  try
    while not Eof do
    begin
      Read(c);
      if c = #13 then // Carriage Return
        Break;
      Result := Result + c;
      if c = #8 then // Back Space
        Write(#8)
      else
        Write(InputMask);
    end;
  finally
    SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), OldMode);
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Writeln(Format(sLineBreak + 'pswd=%s',[GetPassword]));
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**Update**: Note that the above code handles the BackSpaces visually, but keeps them embedded in the password, which might not be what you want.
In that case the following code would filter them out:

```
  if c = #13 then // Carriage Return
    Break;
  if (c = #8) and (Length(Result) > 0) then  // Back Space
  begin
    Delete(Result, Length(Result), 1);
    Write(#8);
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := Result + c;
    Write(InputMask);
  end;
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to just not add #8 by moving `result := result+c` to the else clause, instead of adding it first, and then deleting it?

Comment: you'll want to remove the previous character if they do a backspace.

Comment: Ah, yes, i see what you mean.

Comment: The "Write(#8)" bit behaves odd for me: the cursor moves back, but the '*' character remains. I struggle to see how this could be intentional and am putting it down to either this being overlooked / no one bothered to comment, or the behaviour is different on my machine. That said, willing to bet it's not my machine as the code appears to do what it's told. My fix for this is "Write(#8' '#8)" instead of "Write(#8)". This goes back 1 char as before, but overwrites the '*' with a space, then writes #8 to go back 1 char again.

Comment: One more minor thing, pressing Backspace when nothing's entered yet writes out an asterisk. Minor code change: if c = #13 then // Carriage Return
  Break;
if c = #8 then  // Back Space
begin
  if Result <> '' then
  begin
    Delete(Result, Length(Result), 1);
    Write(#8' '#8);
  end;
end else
begin
  Result := Result + c;
  Write(InputMask);
end;

Answer (score 2):

I have a unit with `procedure ConsoleGetPassword(const caption: String; var Password: string);` which does what you want

see http://gist.github.com/570659

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

const
  BUF_LEN = 1024;

var
  amt, i, cmode: cardinal;
  buf: packed array[0..BUF_LEN - 1] of char;

begin
  try

    Write('Enter password: ');
    GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), cmode);
    SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), cmode and not ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT);
    ReadConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), @buf[0], BUF_LEN, amt, nil);
    SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), cmode);

    Writeln;
    Writeln;

    Writeln('You entered: ');
    for i := 0 to amt - 3 do
      Write(buf[i]);
    Writeln;
    Writeln;

    Writeln('Done');
    Readln;

  except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
      Readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: I tried Francesca's solution and yours. The key difference is yours doesn't mask (thus not revealing password length or any input activity, whilst still "supporting" left/right/backspace/delete). One minor issue, not entering a password causes a squirt of some random memory. The other minor issue is that pressing Up/Down keys and pressing Enter will put a previously entered command into the password (albeit, whatever was entered as password previously does not make it into the command history); perhaps Up/Down keys should be filtered out. Overall I prefer Francesca's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ConsolePasswordInput.aspx), it may be in C#, but it does give you the right clues and the direction to take, involving [ReadConsoleInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961(VS.85).aspx) and [WriteConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401(VS.85).aspx) API